# Wrong value returned when defining a C function in one file and using in another file

Tags: c, function

I define a function, let's say myfun in file2.c. myfun returns a float value. In file1.c I don't have any declaration for this function. I directly call myfun without any prior declaration and assign it's return type to an integer variable, let's call it retValInt. I compile them together. When I print retValInt, it gives me garbage. Why doesn't it cast the returned value and give the appropriate integer?

The following is the exact code:

```
//file1.c
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int retValInt = myfun(123.456);
    printf("The value returned is %d\n",retValInt);
    return 0;
}

//------------------------
//file2.c
float myfun(float a)
{
    return a;
}
```

I expected the output to be 123, but it is 446676599.

Comment: It compiles in C. sorry for the c++ tag

Comment: You are not declaring `myfun` before using it (header, extern, etc?).

Comment: As written, it will not compile in C either.

Comment: You can't do like that!

Answer (score 2):

How could the compiler possibly know, when compiling `main`,  that `myfun` returns a `float` that needs to be cast to an `int`?

You're asking why the compiler didn't make the code do something it could not possibly have known it needed to make the code do. So the answer is obvious -- the compiler had no way to know that's what you wanted. In fact, it is reasonable for the compiler to assume that if you wanted it to do that, you would have told it to. So one can argue that the behavior you seem to expect would actually be incorrect and quite baffling. (You never told the compiler to do that, so doing it would be bad.)

Answer (score 1):

In C, specifically in C89 (but not in C99 or C11!), functions that have not been declared are implicitly assumed to have return type `int`. If your actual function does not have that return type, your program is ill-formed (it has undefined behaviour), and no diagnostic is required.

Your code is not valid C99, but compiler support for C99 is half-hearted at best.

Comment: Previous to C99 that is

Answer (score 0):

To write a prototype before using the function.

```
float myfun(float);
int main()
```